# Octave claims my excel file has no sheets in it

Tags: octave

Octave isn't read my excel files correctly.

It seems like octave thinks that my excel file has no sheets in it. However, the file it is trying to read does have a sheet with columns of data. I've tried to edit the file a few times and change values.

This the code that it is executing.

```
SectionData=xlsread('Input/Beams.xlsx');
```

And this error message appears when my function tries to read the Excel file.

```
error: xls2oct: worksheet number 1 > number of worksheets in file (0)
```

Comment: Please post your code that calls `xlsopen`. Note that Octave uses COM to read Excel files so you must have Office Excel installed on your computer as well. Are you attempting to use an OOXML (`*.xlsx`) file or an Office 97-2003 (`.xls`) file?

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to read the file, it will be helpful for the people to answer.

Comment: Which version of Octave and the io package do you use? Sometimes updating just helps, and thus could be the fastest solution.

Comment: I've got the latest versions of both octave and the io pakage. Excel 2017 is installed aswell.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with another Excel file? Is your `Beams.xlsx` somehow "special", was it generated by some other application?

Comment: This is a pretty specific Octave issue. Please come over to the Octave bug tracker at https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/octave and post this as a bug report there, where you can attach your actual `.xlsx` file and the Octave maintainers can figure out what's going on.